# Javascript chrome console error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, logic

While looking at my code with console in chrome i saw this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment   LINE 99`

But i can't understand what's wrong here

```
function drawMatrix(matrix, offset) {
matrix.forEach((row, y) => {           //THATS LINE 99
    row.forEach((value, x) => {        //OF COURSE THATS LINE 100
        if (value !== 0) {
            context.fillStyle = colors[value];
            context.strokeStyle = "#dee5e3";
            context.lineWidth = 0.1;
            context.strokeRect(x + offset.x, y + offset.y , 1, 1);
            context.fillRect(x + offset.x,
                             y + offset.y,
                             1, 1);
        }
    });
});}
```

I'm pretty sure there must be an error even at line 100 then, probably related to `=>` but i can't understand what kind. Can you help me?

Comment: or the error could be somewhere else and line numbers are off

Comment: it would be pretty useless to signal the line?

Comment: wfm, have you done any debugging around the issue?

Comment: Can you reproduce issue at stacksnippets?

Comment: that's the fact, i get this error in CHROME `37.0.2062.120`   but i don't get the error in CHROME `61.0.3163.100`  Do you think the issue is related to the usage of a old versione? maybe => operator not implemented?

Comment: @ducajack then the problem IS line 99. Chrome 37.x does not know about ES2015. (Arrow Function), but Chrome 61.x does

Comment: yes, corrected my comment :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error says "left-hand side in assignment", so look for a maybe fault "assignment" like var a = b, and a is not present in this scope or something like this.

So, as @epascarello says, maybe the line number in the console does not match.